# How can i install my Wi-max USB modem in Ubutu 13.04?

Tags: usb-modem

I have installed **Ubuntu 13.04** . Now I want know how to install my Wi-max USB modem's driver in my Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

To get the driver for Wi-max installed, run next command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install madwimax
```

Or install it using Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: USC]

Comment: What does **madwimax** mean in the above command line? **Note:** I am an absolute beginner.

Comment: @RedwanulKarim madwimax is an reverse-engineered Linux driver for mobile WiMAX (802.16e) devices - isn't this what you wanted?